# How to parallelize a for loop without sharing any info across the different cpus/cores

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to parallelize a task in python using the joblib library.

The following is my code

```
{import other libraries and packages needed}
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

Lambda = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

define mainfunc(arg):
   {perform a whole bunch of operations using arg}

Parallel(n_jobs=-2,delayed(mainfunc)(arg[i]) for i in range(len(Lambda)))
```

Now my code runs all fine. But after analyzing the data generated for all the different lambda values, I find that the different parallel processes might be sharing some info which I don't want. I want the 5 different processes to run in absolute isolation from each other.

Comment: if you want to parallelize a loop, you want to process the same data in a smaller wall clock time, but that will not happen if the parallel tasks don't use the same data

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rioV8. I guess I can be explicit in saying that I need to run myfunc 5 times, with different values of Lambda, and that the 5 different runs should not communicate anyhow amongst each other. I literally want to create 5 different machines in some sense

Comment: @rioV8 maybe I can be even more specific and say that the operations performed in the myfunc seem to be interleaved for different lambda values. That is, some process that has been performed for, say Lambda = 2, seems to have an effect on some process for say Lambda = 5. 
(This I know based on the final 5 data sets I have at the end, and their correlations with each other)

Comment: what data are they sharing? Are the tasks initiated as forks or threads, Python does not do threads, Python is single threaded

Comment: They all start with the same initial condition, which is a N^3 array. And that is it. 
For different Lambda values, the N^3 array gets evolved according to some scheme using the myfunc function (the specifics of which depends on Lambda value).

Comment: One another thing I should say is that there are variables that are being updated in the myfunc function, and the associated redundancy may result in this issue of mine. For instance, the initial N^3 data is defined as psi. Then it is evolved according to some Lambda dependent scheme and after a bunch of steps psi gets rewritten with the new data obtained. Could it be that since the psi variable name is the same for all the different Lambda processes, they could somehow get intertwined along their evolution?